# possible to check cross fields constraint in the middle of method

Tags: java, spring, validation, java-8, constraints

We have a service class in Java 8 SpringBoot application that needs to check if a field of object A matches object B passed in as a method parameter. It would have worked beautifully using ConstraintValidator if all method signatures took Object A & Object B as parameters.

Method in service class:

```
@Override
@MyCheck
public String serviceDoLogic(Object B, Object A) {
    ......
}
```

Validator class:

```
@SupportedValidationTarget(ValidationTarget.PARAMETERS)
public class MyCheckValidator implements ConstraintValidator<MyCheck, Object[]> {


  @Override
  public boolean isValid(
        Object[] value,
        ConstraintValidatorContext context) {

    if( value.length <2 ) {
        return true;
    }
    if ( ! value[0].equals(value[1].myField()) {
       return false;
    }
    return true;
  }
}
```

Unfortunately, for some methods in the service class, it can only take a String identifier for Object A (as it is the only thing known at the time), and within the service, it needs to call DAO to get Object A. Thus the constraint cannot be triggered for them.

Any solution, other than having the check logic embedded in every method that needs it, to get it done in an elegant way? Hope I explain it well

Many thanks in advance

Comment: can you may be show a simplified example?

Comment: and I don't wanna add a DAO call in my constraint validator class, as service will need to call DAO anyways to use Object A through the rest of the method

Comment: so it seems your pain comes from the fact that you will call your DAO twice, right?

Comment: if I wanna use constraint validator as it should.